# Выяснить заказчика рекламного блока Google AdSense

Tags: реклама, google-adsense

Какой-то скрипт регулярно подключает Google рекламу в шапке сайта. Можно ли как-то по строке подключения скрипта определить, какой аккаунт является заказчиком данной рекламы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Google Chrome есть такое расширение: [Google Publisher Toolbar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-publisher-toolbar/omioeahgfecgfpfldejlnideemfidnkc)

Если в ней включить вот эту опцию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то будет показываться рекламодатель:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Да, ищите data-ad-client. Там будет номер.

Comment: Окей, вижу номер. А как юзера то по нему найти?